# creating metapackage with catkin-tools

Tags: ros, catkin, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to create a ROS metapackage with [catkin-tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? With `catkin_make` its possible with:

```
catkin_create_pkg <MY_META_PACKAGE> --meta
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364196/creating-metapackage-with-catkin-tools/) by [fjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/9816/fjp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2020-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, `catkin_create_pkg` is a standalone executable not related to `catkin_make` or `catkin-tools` (other than the `catkin` prefix and that it creates a metapacakge to be built with either of the two tools).

Use `catkin_create_pkg` to create the metapackage and you can compile with either of the two build tools above...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1